# netsh add sslcert parameter is incorrect from cmd

Tags: cmd, netsh

Note that, while there is a lot on this issue already, it invariably covers either using this from powershell (where braces and dashes can be an issue) or a typo in the docs where ipport is followed by a colon.

I am in cmd

```
C:> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8180 appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} certhash=‎1234567890
The parameter is incorrect.
```

In actual usagge I'm using the correct certhash I got from my certificate store - not the obviously fake one above

So what is going on? Is there a way to get more info?

Comment: _I'm using the correct `certhash`_… Supposedly "_The SHA hash of the certificate. This hash is 20 bytes long and specified as a hex string_" instead of fake `1234567890`? However, there is a harmful format symbol **Left-To-Right Mark**  (Unicode `U+200E`) after _Equals Sign_ in your `certhash=‎1234567890`. Sorry, I don't understand why?

Comment: What the heck...that's...interesting @JosefZ thanks...I don't really understand why either...I copied this out of the certificate thumbnail details...the only thing I can think of is it was in there alread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Explained in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271465/netsh-add-sslcert-parameter-is-incorrect-from-cmd?noredirect=1#comment63971915_38271465):

> *I'm using the correct `certhash`*… Supposedly "*The SHA hash of the certificate. This hash is 20 bytes long and specified as a hex
>   string*" instead of fake `1234567890`?
>
> However, there is a harmful format symbol Left-To-Right Mark (Unicode
>   `U+200E`) after *Equals Sign* in your `certhash=‎1234567890`

Screenshot taken from [Unicode Analyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unicode-analyzer/pipjflhdnjcdflbkmoldkkpphmhcfaio):

[image: Left-To-Right Mark]

Another way to detect *invisible* characters using my [Alt KeyCode Finder](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602) script:

```
==> mycharmap h=‎1

Ch Unicode    Alt?    CP    IME    Alt   Alt0    IME 0405/cs-CZ; CP852; ANSI 1250

 h  U+0068     104        …104…    104   0104    Latin Small Letter H

 =  U+003D      61         …61…     61    061    Equals Sign

 ‎  U+200E    8206         …14…                  Left-To-Right Mark
                    CP862 he-IL          0253    (ANSI 1255) Hebrew
                    CP720 ar-EG          0253    (ANSI 1256) Arabic

 1  U+0031      49         …49…     49    049    Digit One

 h=‎1
```

==> chcp
Active code page: 852

Comment: Could you edit the conversation into the answer? Might make it easier to read for anyone who finds this later